# How do you tell how many decimal places are in a user's input?

Tags: c, rounding

I am trying to write a program that takes a number and a desired amount of decimal places and then rounds that number appropriately by comparing the distances of that number from that number +1.

```
int main() {
double tester;
int numberOfDecimals;

printf("Enter a number to be rounded: ");
scanf("%lf",&tester);
printf("%d rounded to how many decimal places? ",tester);
scanf("%d", &numberOfDecimals);
```

After I ask for the number of decimals they want the number rounded to, how do I check to see how many decimal places are in the number they input?

Comment: If you read directly into a double, you don't know how many digits they actually entered. Consider reading into a string, and then sscanf into a variable.

Comment: Read in a string and parse it instead of having `scanf` parse for you.

Comment: You want to round to a specified number of decimal places - got that.  Why does it make _any_ difference what the number of decimal places the number was entered?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
double tester;
int numberOfDecimals;
char strBuf[255+1];
char *decimalPoint;
int decimalPlacesOfInput = 0;

printf("Enter a number to be rounded: ");
fgets(strBuf, sizeof(strBuf), stdin);

decimalPoint=strchr(strBuf, '.');
if(decimalPoint)
   {
   ++decimalPoint;
   while(isdigit(*decimalPoint))
      {
      ++decimalPlacesOfInput;
      ++decimalPoint;
      } 
   }

printf("Number entered with %d decimal places.\n", decimalPlacesOfInput);

tester=atof(strBuf);
printf("%d rounded to how many decimal places? ",tester);
scanf("%d", &numberOfDecimals);
...
```